# XSL sort items by condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<main>
    <cat>
        <id>12</id>
        <name>Pizza-Tuno</name>
        <depends>
            <depend>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Tuno</name>
                <type>Food</type>
            </depend>
            <depend>
                <id>122</id>
                <name>Knife</name>
                <type>Tool</type>
            </depend>
            <depend>
                <id>1123</id>
                <name>Water</name>
                <type>Food</type>
            </depend>
            <depend>
                <id>417</id>
                <name>Scissors</name>
                <type>Tool</type>
            </depend>
        </depends>
    </cat>
</main>
```

Currently i have this xsl:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Foods:
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-tempaltes match="main/cat" />
        </ul>

        Tools:
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-tempaltes match="main/cat" />
        </ul>

    </body>

</html>

  <xsl:template match="main/cat">

        <li>

                <xsl:value-of select="name" />


        </li>

    </xsl:template>
```

And i want this output:

```
 <html>
        <body>
            Foods:
            <ul>
                <li>Tuno</li>
                        <li>Water<li/>


            </ul>

            Tools:
            <ul>
                <li>Knife</li>
                        <li>Scissors</li>
            </ul>

        </body>

    </html>
```

How can i do that with xsl? The  elements should divide by the  element..

Comment: What you have there is not XSLT. It's riddled with semantic and syntax errors. How hard can it be to copy and paste the XSLT you have? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `xsl:apply-templates` processes nodes in so-called document order. To change the order of nodes, you can include `xsl:sort` instruction into the `xsl:apply-templates` call.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="...">
    <xsl:sort select="..."/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Note, that by default sorting is applied in ASCII order. But you can tell the processor that you actually want to sort by numbers:

```
<xsl:sort select="..." data-type="number"/>
```

Having said that, your XSLT needs to be modified in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:template match="document-node()">
        <html>
            <body>
                Foods:
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="main/cat/depends/depend[type = 'Food']">
                        <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </ul>

                Tools:
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="main/cat/depends/depend[type = 'Tool']">
                        <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="depend">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in using `document-node()` over `/*`?

Comment: Not really. It's a matter of preference. I like `document-node()`, `element()`, `attribute()`, etc. functions because of their explicitness. For instance, at first it wasn't clear to me, what does "*" shorthand suppose to mean. For me it is was "everything", but it occurred that it stands for elements only.

Comment: Thank You serhiy.h. That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: BTW, I have just read that `data-type` attribute is considered outdated in XSLT 2.0. The sorting of numbers can (and should) be executed based on the data type of the input: `<xsl:sort select="xs:integer(...)"/>`